# R dplyr filter rows based on conditions from several selected columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a dataframe `DF`, and I want to filter it based on condition from several selected columns.

For instance, I want to filter rows in DF that fulfil the condition that  this row contains any values that are **smaller than 0.03** in column `PCS_AB`, `PCS_AD`, `PCS_BD`.

```
DF <- cbind.data.frame(A = c(100, 10, 13),
                       B = c(33, 44, 12),
                       D = c(110, 21, 22),
                       PCS_AB = c(0.03, 0.001, 0.3),
                       PCS_AD = c(0.01, 0.2, 0.33),
                       PCS_BD = c(0.99, 1.0, 0.45))
```

I can achieve it by the following code:

```
DF_filter <- DF %>%
  filter(PCS_AB < 0.03 | PCS_AD < 0.03 | PCS_BD < 0.03)
```

But I want something simpler like the pseudo code as following:

```
DF2 <- DF %>%
      filter(any(starts_with("PCS")) < 0.03)
```

Is it possible with dplyr? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `if_any` from the version `1.0.4` of `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
   filter(if_any(starts_with("PCS"), ~ . <= 0.03))
```

-output

```
#   A  B   D PCS_AB PCS_AD PCS_BD
#1 100 33 110  0.030   0.01   0.99
#2  10 44  21  0.001   0.20   1.00
```

---

It is also possible `filter_at` with `any_vars` (soon to be deprecated)

```
DF %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("PCS")), any_vars(. <= 0.03))
```

-output

```
#    A  B   D PCS_AB PCS_AD PCS_BD
#1 100 33 110  0.030   0.01   0.99
#2  10 44  21  0.001   0.20   1.00
```

---

Or use `rowSums` to create the logical vector

```
DF %>%
    filter(rowSums(select(., starts_with('PCS')) < 0.03) > 0)
```